# Корректно ли словосочетание "знаки пунктуации"?

Tags: пунктуация

Задавая вопросы о знаках препинания, многие употребляют слова "знаки пунктуации". Допустимо ли это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пунктуация определяется как **система знаков** препинания, поэтому можно сказать "знаки пунктуации, пунктуационные знаки".

Например: http://www.rusresh.ru/znaki-punktuacii-v-russkom-jazyke.html

В то же время эти выражения **применяются значительно реже,** но в некоторых случаях ими можно воспользоваться для избежания повторов в конкретном тексте.